# How to custom hexagon shape in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, cs6, shapes

I love ask question button style in this site

[image]

I'm trying create it in photoshop, when I scaling the hexagon shape it looks very bad, as image below.

[image]

Please anyone give me advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use scale .. instead stretch your shape. I mean by selecting the three handles and move it. this will stretch the middle segments to the desire shape.

Comment: @hsawires Can you tell how to select the handles in photoshop. I'm really newbie in Photoshop :)

Comment: with the white arrow you can drag a window to select the three left or right handles. or you can select one by one while pressing shift. they will turn into black handles and after selecting them drag them to a new location, be sure to press shift while dragging or use the left or right arrows. that's it.

Comment: @hsawires Thank you. I think we can do it with pencil tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you didn't get it from the comments here is how to do it.

First make 6 sided polygon on page (I assume you can do this)
[image: 6 Sided Polygone]
Then using the white mouse (direct selection tool) [image: Direct Selection Tool] If you can't find it there might be a black one instead hold it down or right click for menu, alternatively you can just press (A).

Then hold down `shift` while clicking on he left three corners (They will change from a hollow square to a filled in one) and use the arrow keys to move them left to your liking. The shape should now look more like this:

[image: Final shape]

Comment: Thank you so much, I have more question that there is any tricks to make sure 2 sides the same after scaled?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand, if you are using the arrow keys both the sides should be exactly the same, It's probably better if you open a new question

Comment: Thank you, I understand now :D. If you don't mind, hope you can show me how to draw [this bracket](http://upanh.biz/images/2015/02/19/UntitledgyNCx.png) using Photoshop, I'm learning draw shapes to building my web layout, thank you so much.

Comment: Sure give me 10 mins

Comment: I have done it (cheating slightly there might be an easier way) but if you create a new question I will upload my pictures

Comment: Ok dude, I'll create new topic.

Comment: Please check it here:

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48501/how-to-cut-of-rectangle-shape-to-create-bracket-in-photoshop