# How to cut of rectangle shape to create bracket in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I want a layer like this:

[image]

I've drawn the rectangle then I made a selection with the marquee selection tool to delete a part of the rectangle but it deleted whole shape. Can anyone please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

Mask those parts out with a layer mask.

Black to hide, white to reveal.

Use black on the parts you want to get rid of.

Long answer:

After you've created the rectangular shape, add a layer mask (located in the bottom of the layers panal, looks like a rectangle with a circle in the middle).

Make a rectangular selection through out the middle of the rectangle.
Fill that recangular selection with black on the layer mask.

Now you should have the desired effect.

Comment: While correct, this answer's very short. Could you elaborate a bit, for example on how to add a layer mask to a layer? You might also mention that 'layer mask hides effects' needs to be checked for the desired effect. Thanks!

Comment: @jvs Thank you so much, it's really easy. More question that how can I rotate it? I can't use Transform for it.

Comment: Do you want to rotate the shape or the mask?

Answer (score 2):

Although it might be best to do it in illustrator you can:
First make a rectangle
[image: Rectangle]
Then rasterize the layer
[image: Rasterize]
Use the select tool to select a square and press delete, this should give you one half of the square bracket.
[image: Cut Square]
You can then Duplicate the layer
[image: Duplicate]
On one of the layers press `Ctrl + T` to transform the shape and then right click and press `Flip Horizontal`
[image: Flip]
You can now move them apart and using the text tool place text in the right position
[image: Final]

That might not be the best way to do it but it would be how I would do it.

Comment: You are now losing a lot of (possible valuable) data by 1) rasterizing the layer, therefore you lost all vector data and 2) because you deleted pixels meaning you cant recover them if you need them on a later state.

Comment: @sam-collins Thank you for details tutorial, it's good but you can try JVS suggestion, it's simple :D